# Where can I find the rules for an eviscerator in Deathwatch?

Tags: weapons, deathwatch

The Memor Nihilis, a Relic of the Flesh Tearers is described as *"a two-handed variant of the Astartes chainsword, more commonly known as an eviscerator"* (Honor the Chapter, p.131). But what are the stats of a regular eviscerator? Just the same as a regular chainsword, except you use two hands? Or is it more powerful? And where can I find these stats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [40K RPG Tools](http://www.40krpgtools.com/) to search through all the Warhammer 40K RPG books.

For the Eviscerator in particular, stats can be found in the other lines in these books:

- Dark Heresy, Inquisitor's Handbook, p 187 (1d10+10 R; Pen 5; Two handed; Tearing, Unwieldy)
- Only War, Core Rulebook, p 185 (2d10 R; Pen 9; Two handed; Razor Sharp, Tearing, Unwieldy)
- Deathwatch, Mark of the Xenos, p 120 (1d10+12 R; Pen 5; Tearing, Unbalanced)

Comment: I took a look at that Deathwatch note, but I noticed that it's incorrect: on that page it talks about the Obliterator's Eviscerator Chainblade (1d10+22 R, Pen 5, Tearing, Unbalanced), which does not work because it is part of the Obliterator's body. Or was this part of an update?

Answer (score 0):

The Warhammer Wikipedia has the following books listed as references for the Evicerator.
http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Eviscerator

Codex: Imperial Guard (4th Edition), p. 34
Codex: Imperial Guard (5th Edition), p. 35
Codex: Witch Hunters (4th Edition), pp. 20-21
Dark Heresy - Blood of Martyrs (RPG), p. 116
Warhammer 40,000: Wargear (2nd Edition)

Comment: I think most of those are for the minis game, which aren't useful for the RPG.

Comment: Only the fourth book is of passing interest, but it's the wrong RPG.

Comment: @Thomas All the 40k RPGs use the same rules and stats, and are compatible. The PCs are just different power levels.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie no they are not (multiple melee attack rules, for example). Anyway, human-sized eviscerator wielded by a Sister of Battle seems smallish for the Space Marine use.

Comment: @JeorMattan Compatible, not identical. They're compatible in the sense that OWoD games are compatible: they all use the same house system, and bits from one are adaptable to the other.